# How to check if value/string in one row of Table 1 is present in Table 2?

Tags: excel

I want to check if a value or text string in a given row in Table 1 is also present in a given column in Table 2. Of course I could do this column by column in Table 1 but with about 50 columns I don't really want to. My data looks something like this:

**Table 1**

```
1 aaa bbb ccc

2 ddd eee fff

3 ggg hhh iii
```

**Table 2**

```
1 bbb

2 xxx

3 ccc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,$A1:$C1)>0,1,0))
```

Press CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER after entering it as opposed to ENTER

This will tell you how many exist in the list on sheet2 for each row in sheet 1